# How do I use REGEXTRACT in Google Sheets to isolate the GCLID?

Tags: html, regex, url, google-sheets, re2

I'm a marketer and Google assigns clicks a Google Click ID (GCLID) on paid traffic. These come through appended to URLs. Sometimes, I need to isolate the value in a Google Sheet using REGEX.

Here's what I've done to extract the GCLID in Sublime Text but it is not yielding the expected result in google sheets:

`(?<=gclid=).*?[?=A-Za-z0-9\-\_]{10,100}`

100 case sensitive alphanumeric characters is the max for these Ids. They also consist of "-" as well as "_".

I believe this is an effective use of a REGEX positive lookback that yields just the GCLID at the end of the URL query.

The use of a `?` in Google Sheets seems to break the expression.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "gclid=([\w-]+)")
```

Note that the `REGEXEXTRACT` function only returns the *captured* substring(s) if the capturing group(s) is defined in the regular expression.

The regex matches

- `gclid=` - a literal string
- `([\w-]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more letters, digits, `_` or `-` (note the `-` at the end of a character class does not have to be escaped to be parsed as a literal hyphen).